# About CakePHP 3 BelongsToMany issue

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have an issue with the following case :

> Users Table

```
id, profile_id, name, created, modified
```

> Profiles Table

```
id, first_name, last_name, gender
```

> Businesses table

```
id, name, created, modified
```

I have a relation table many to many to link `profiles` to `businesses` : `businesses_profiles`

```
id, business_id, profile_id, created, modified
```

When i try to create a new business, I would like to link directly logged in user profile id to the business I'm creating.

in my `profileTable`, I've added in `initialize()` :

```
  $this->belongsToMany('Businesses', [
        'alias' => 'Businesses',
        'foreignKey' => 'profile_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'business_id',
        'joinTable' => 'businesses_profiles'
    ]);
```

in my `businessesTable`, I've also put in `initialize()` method:

```
 $this->belongsToMany('Profiles', [
        'alias' => 'Profiles',
        'foreignKey' => 'business_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'profile_id',
        'joinTable' => 'businesses_profiles'
    ]);
```

In each entities `Business` & `Profile`, I put respectively in right context :

```
protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => true,
    'id' => false,
    'businesses' => true,
    '_joinData' => true
];
```

and :

```
 protected $_accessible = [
    'name' => true,
    'slug' => true,
    'active' => true,
    'hash' => true,
    'data' => true,
    'approved' => true,
    'created' => true,
    'modified' => true,
    'profiles' => true,
    '_joinData' => true
];
```

Nothings work about saving in my `businesses_profiles` table.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Best,

Laurent.

Comment: Check out [this plugin](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint), it does this sort of thing transparently for you.

Comment: Could you post the code for saving the business as well? Have you checked if any validation methods are generated? Also have you had a look on this part of the documentation about how to save associated data, it is really helpful: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I've found the solution by using the link() method provided by CakePHP.

I'll share my add function here, if it can help others :

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help.  I've found the solution by using the link() method provided by CakePHP.

I'll share my add function here, if it can help others :

```
public function add()
{
    $business = $this->Businesses->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $business = $this->Businesses->patchEntity($business, $this->request->getData());

        $business->set('hash');
        $business->set('active', 0);
        $business->set('slug');

        $profile = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Profiles')->get($this->_currentUser->profile_id);

        if ($this->Businesses->save($business)) {

            **$this->Businesses->Profiles->link($business, [$profile]);**
            $this->Flash->success(__('The business has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        else

        {
            debug($business->getErrors()); // debug
            $this->Flash->error(__('The business could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('business'));
}
```